# how to perfectly align text vertically in tailwind css

Tags: flexbox, tailwind-css

i want to align my text verticaly with tailwind css and im stuck

[you see the black line i want all my text to start there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKdu5.png)

```
 <div class="w-60 bg-red-200 flex items-center flex-col">
      <h1 class="">Loremipsm dolor.</h1>
      <h1 class="">Lorem, hj dolor.</h1>
      <h1 class="">Lom, ipolor.</h1>
      <h1 class="">Lorem, ipsumolor.</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Remove the `items-center` class.

Comment: it worked but the problem is i want theme to be in the center and start all in one line ... is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap all `h1` tags inside one `div` that would work look the example:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/m24PPlLUfH

Comment: @kabylecoder happy coding kaby :)

Answer (score 0):

If you using tailwind & flexboxes probably you should use class

**justify-center**

[documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-items#basic-usage) about it

Comment: https://dev.to/afif/never-make-your-text-container-a-flexbox-container-m9p